# Docker with Symfony 5

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure docker for the symfony demo.
But my setting is wrong.
on the address http://localhost:7000/fr/blog/ I receive the error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
```

And on the address: http://localhost:7003/, I have a

```
mysqli :: real_connect () error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I put my sources on Git. https://github.com/dzeta49/symfony5docker
Could you tell me my configuration error? 
Thank you very much for your help and your indulgence, I am starting.

Comment: It's good that you put the link to your repository but try to put your configuration file for the database connection in the question.

Comment: sorry by completing this question, another identical has been opened : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443891/docker-with-symfony-5-configuration