# Docker with Symfony 5 configuration

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure docker for the symfony demo.
But my setting is wrong.
on the address
http://localhost:7000/fr/blog/

I have an error:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
>   And on the address: http://localhost:7003/, I have a mysqli :: real_connect () error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
>   I put my sources on Git. https://github.com/dzeta49/symfony5docker

Could you tell me my configuration error? 
Thank you very much for your help and your indulgence, I am starting.

docker\docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "7002:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - APP_SECRET=${APP_SECRET}
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@database:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}?serverVersion=5.7
    volumes:
      - ../my_project_demo:/var/www

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../my_project_demo:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
      - "7001:443"

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=database
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - "7003:80"
```

docker\env

```
DATABASE_NAME=symfony
DATABASE_USER=appuser
DATABASE_PASSWORD=apppassword
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

my_project_demo\env

```
DATABASE_NAME=symfony
DATABASE_USER=appuser
DATABASE_PASSWORD=apppassword
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_URL=mysql://appuser:apppassword@database:3306/symfony?serverVersion=5.7
```

Comment: Open a shell in your php-fpm container and ping database to verify the container is reachable. If OK, install mysql client and do an interactive login to debug the connection process

Comment: Now http://localhost:7000/fr/blog/ and http://localhost:7003/ are OK. But if i try a command line "php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load", i have error  "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Hte inconnu". it is my "DATABASE_URL=mysql://appuser:apppassword@database:3306/symfony?serverVersion=5.7" in my_project_demo\.env ??

Comment: I found ! the command is "docker-compose exec php-fpm bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load"

Comment: is it possible to have only one env file?